# Localstorage not working properly in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, local-storage

I am using bootstrap tabs in my theme. I am storing current tab No. into `localstorage`. After executing my functions I am reloading my page and taking `tab#` from `localstorage`. It's working fine with chrome but with Firefox not working properly. Following is my code:

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e){
   var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
   window.location.hash = id;
   localStorage.setItem('tab',id);
});
```

And I am getting from storage:

```
localStorage.getItem('tab');
```

E.g. In Chrome it's giving `#tab3` but in Firefox its giving `htab3`. Replacing `#` with `h`. How can I fix this?

Comment: It's very doubtful that FF has such a serious problem with `localStorage`. What do you see if you do `console.log(id)`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Firefox does this since on 59.0.2 seems to be working fine.

If you have an issue with special characters though going with base64 could be a work around.

```
var myStorage = {
    getItem: function _get(key) {
        return atob(localStorage.getItem(key));
    },
    setItem: function _set(key, val) {
        return localStorage.setItem(key, btoa(val));
    }
}


//Testing it
myStorage.setItem('tabs', '#four');
console.info(myStorage.getItem('tabs'));
```